# onClick for images in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-viewpager

I've a image slider made with the help of `ViewPager.` I want to show different `toast` messages when clicked in different images loaded by `ViewPager`, how can i do that?

this my activity where image slider is shown:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public static final String MAIN = "OTHER";
    private static ViewPager mPager;
    private static int currentPage = 0;
    private static final Integer[] XMEN=
            {R.drawable.benz2, R.drawable.benz2,
                    R.drawable.benz2};
    private ArrayList<Integer> XMENArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(...);
        init();
}
private void init() {
        for(int i=0;i<XMEN.length;i++)
            XMENArray.add(XMEN[i]);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(new com.example.nepali_test.MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,XMENArray));
        CircleIndicator indicator = (CircleIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(mPager);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == XMEN.length) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };
        Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 3000, 3000);
    }
```

and this is the adapter of the viewpager:

```java
public class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Integer> images;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> images) {
        this.context = context;
        this.images=images;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
        View myImageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide, view, false);
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) myImageLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.image);
        myImage.setImageResource(images.get(position));
        view.addView(myImageLayout, 0);
        return myImageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }
}
```

I tried to make by adding

```
if (currentPage==1){
            Toast.makeText(this, "page 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

in `init()` but it didn't work.

Comment: Try answer for the same @babukancha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i could understand you need to display the toast when clicking on the image in each page of a `ViewPager` in which case an easy way is to add an `onClickListener` to your `ImageView` inside your adapter's `instantiateItem` method. So you should change/replace your method with this:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull final ViewGroup view, final int position) {
    View myImageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide, view, false);
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) myImageLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.image);
    myImage.setImageResource(images.get(position));
    myImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "page "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    view.addView(myImageLayout, 0);
    return myImageLayout;
}
```

Comment: Hi @babukancha if my answer helped you please select it as the answer or upvote in order to help others with similar issues and also improve my reputation.
As for passing intents simply write the code in the place where you have the code for toast inside `onClick` 
Something like `Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivityName.class);
context.startActivity(intent);`
And add flags or arguments as per your need, but that is a whole different topic from your original question also making use of interfaces for clicks would be beneficial in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, final int pos) { //have to make final so we can see it inside of onClick()
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_PAGE, null);

    page.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            //this will log the page number that was click
            Log.i("TAG", "This page was clicked: " + pos);
        }
    });


    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(page, 0);
    return page;
}
```

Hope this will work!

Comment: sir? where should i place that code? in onCreate or in init() or somewhere?

Comment: Add this in your method of adapter Object instantiateItem

Comment: sir? im not being able to add toast message or any intents; im facing error in context.

Comment: create interface method for this click same like you do in your class MyClassImage, Add one another method over there and access it in your MainActivity

Comment: Add one more method here public interface MyClassImage{
    void imageClick(String id);

}

Comment: please update the answer and say where where should i keep those? I'm not getting :(

Comment: please help me @KalpeshRupani sir?

Comment: sir error is showing in myClassImage and position of adapter and also in mainactivity

Comment: Its MyClassImage.onPageClicked, remove position and try

Comment: nothing is working all are showing error please help me @KalpeshRupani sir

Answer (score 1):

Make Image click interface in adapter class

```
public class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<Integer> images;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
MyClassImage myClassImage;

public interface MyClassImage{
    void imageClick(String id);

}

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> images,MyClassImage myClassImage) {
    this.context = context;
    this.images=images;
    this.myClassImage=myClassImage;

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.size();
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
    View myImageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.z_slide_pager_item, view, false);
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) myImageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
    myImage.setImageResource(images.get(position));
    view.addView(myImageLayout, 0);
    final int id=images.get(position);
    final String imgId=String.valueOf(id);


    myImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myClassImage.imageClick(imgId);
        }
    });
    return myImageLayout;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}
}
```

and implement it on your MainActivity class

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyAdapter.MyClassImage {
public static final String MAIN = "OTHER";
private static ViewPager mPager;
private static int currentPage = 0;
private static final Integer[] XMEN= {R.drawable.benz2, R.drawable.benz2, R.drawable.benz2};
private ArrayList<Integer> XMENArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(...);
init();
}
    private void init() {
    for(int i=0;i<XMEN.length;i++)
        XMENArray.add(XMEN[i]);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(new com.example.nepali_test.MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,XMENArray,this));
    CircleIndicator indicator = (CircleIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (currentPage == XMEN.length) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
        }
    };
    Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
    swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
        }
    }, 3000, 3000);
}

@Override
public void imageClick(String id) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "page "+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Thanks.

Comment: error is showing in ```myClassImage``` of  ```public void onClick(View v) {
            myClassImage.imageClick(imgId);
        }```